# Writing TeX file name at the top of the processed document for article class

Tags: textpos, xpatch

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos}
\newcommand{\insertname}{%
  \begin{textblock}{2}(5,-0.5)
    \bfseries{\jobname.tex}
  \end{textblock}
}
\begin{document}
\insertname
Some text.
\end{document}
```

This places the name of the LaTeX file at the top of the output PDF. However, I'd like this handled automatically, using `xpatch`, if possible. Then I won't need to manually insert the macro into the body, but will have this handled in the preamble. I've tried using `\xpretocmd` with `\maketitle` and `\titlepage` as arguments in turn, but it does not work. Any suggestions how I can do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand{\insertname}{%
  \begin{textblock}{2}(5,-0.5)
    \bfseries{\jobname.tex}
  \end{textblock}
}
\xpretocmd{\maketitle}{\insertname}{}{}
%\xpretocmd{\titlepage}{\insertname}{}{}
\begin{document}
%\insertname
Some text.
\end{document}
```

The answer by tohecz looks good, but doesn't work with a simple letter example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\address{Sender address}
\signature{Some person}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\jobname\quad\the\day.~\the\month.~\the\year}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient address}

\opening{Dear Sir/Madam,}

Some stuff

\closing{Thanking you}
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% picture loaded to be able to use 'units in \put
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  % change reference point to page upper left
  \AtPageUpperLeft{
    \put(1cm,-1cm){\textbf{\jobname}}
  }
}
% this is just to have some contents
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

`\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` just added to the next shipped out page. Remove the `*` and it is added to all pages.

---

Centered version

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% picture loaded to be able to use 'units in \put
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,calc}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  % change reference point to page upper left
  \AtPageUpperLeft{
    \put(\oddsidemargin+1in+0.5\textwidth,-1cm){%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\textbf{\jobname}}}
  }
}
% this is just to have some contents
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you suggest some automated way to center the text between the left and right margins? I've switched to em, but the position still seems to be moving about.

Comment: See the update. BTW `em` is a unit of measure, how should that center anything?

Comment: Thanks. I thought em is measured relative to the page. so a x-coordinate measured in em should be invariant across different documents, but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: EM is a dynamic unit of measure, it corresponds to the current font size, often roughly the width of an M.

Answer (score 4):

You need to *use* `\maketitle` if you want that `\insertname` is executed.

However the simplistic solution of doing `\AtBeginDocument{\insertname}` will not work if `\maketitle` is used in the document, because `\maketitle` does `\newpage`.

A more complex workaround is needed if you plan not using `\maketitle` in your document. If you plan to use it, then `\@maketitle` is the macro to be patched:

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage}{\newpage\insertname}{}{\ddt}
\makeatother
```

so `\insertname` is executed after the `\newpage`.

If you want it independent of the presence of `\maketitle`, the only reliable way seems to be with a suitable page style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@faheem{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \def\@oddhead{\hfil\textbf{\jobname.tex}}%
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{faheem}}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{plain}{faheem}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{A}\author{B}
\maketitle
Some text.
\end{document}
```

If you comment `\maketitle` you'll get the same header.

---

For completeness, here's a different strategy with `atbegshi`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\newcommand{\insertname}{%
  \put(\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth,-1cm){%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{\jobname.tex}}%
  }%
  \gdef\insertname{}%
}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\insertname}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{A}\author{B}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Modify the placement parameters; with this setting, the filename is placed with its right edge flush with the right margin, the baseline at 1cm from the top of the paper.

Comment: If it just has to go in the very first page I'd just use `eso-pic` and `\AtBeginDocument`

Comment: @daleif I want it at the top of the first page. Can you give more details of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Do I miss something or you can simply use the standard headers as I often do?

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\jobname\quad\the\day.~\the\month.~\the\year}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

This inserts the `\jobname` and the date of compilation into the header of every page. If you already have something in your header and you want to put this a bit higher, you can use the following construct:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\jobinhead{\jobname\quad\the\day.\the\month.\the\year}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  blabla%
  \smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\llap{\jobinhead}}}%
}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \leavevmode
  \smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\rlap{\jobinhead}}}%
  blabla%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

If you don't want to load `mathtools`, you can simulate `\llap{abc}` and `\rlap{abc}` by `\hbox to 0pt{\hss abc}` and `\hbox to 0pt{abc\hss}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tohecz. However, I can't get this to show anything using a minimal example. I'll stick it in chat.