# Overlapping text using eso-pic with scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2, eso-pic

I'm using `eso-pic` to annotate this letter, using `scrlttr2`, courtesy of 
[an earlier answer by daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155757/3406) to the question ["Writing TeX file name at the top of the processed document for article class"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155745/3406).
As you can see, there is a little problem with overlapping text. What is the simplest way to fix this?

The annotation is generated by Mercurial and represents the last commit timestamp (see 
[Embedding Mercurial version control information in a TeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184743/3406)),
but I'm hard-wiring it in, because this question doesn't have anything to do with Mercurial.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=false,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
% Add code to annotate file with file name and hash of last hg cset to change the file.                                                          
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  % change reference point to page upper left                                                                                                    
  \AtPageUpperLeft{
    \put(\oddsidemargin+1in+0.5\textwidth,-1cm){%                                                                                                
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\textbf{shaw.tex} 09da3da30168bc8301b68b894b0414cd87ba0a16 2014-08-30 18:13 +0530 } }
  }
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{H. G. Wells}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Spade House\\ 5281 Radnor Cliff Crescent (West Side)\\ Sandgate, Kent}

\def\today{1st January, 1895}
\begin{letter}{
    George Bernard Shaw,\\
    Shaw's Corner,\\
    Bibbs Hall Lane,\\
    Ayot St. Lawrence, Hertfordshire\\}

\opening{Dear Shaw,}

You suck!

\closing{Sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to Steven for his helpful response.

I remember the last time I asked about annotating a LaTeX file, per 
[What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169808/3406)
for example, someone made the distinction about writing on top of the TeX without regard to what was already there (which means it might overwrite stuff), or putting it in a "provided" slot, say at the top of the page. I don't remember the details. Does anyone have a link to something about this?

Answer (score 1):

I employed my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831) to your problem.  It uses `everypage` rather than `eso-pic` (see below for `eso-pic` version).  Note that, as written, `\atxy` only places the overtext on the page from which it is invoked.  However, if you wanted the overtext on every page, you could change the `\AddThispageHook` to `\AddEverypageHook`.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=false,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
% Add code to annotate file with file name and hash of last hg cset to change the file.                                                          
%\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\atxy{.5\paperwidth}{0.5cm}{\makebox[0pt]{%
\textbf{shaw.tex} 09da3da30168bc8301b68b894b0414cd87ba0a16 2014-08-30 18:13 +0530}}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{H. G. Wells}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Spade House\\ 5281 Radnor Cliff Crescent (West Side)\\ Sandgate, Kent}

\def\today{1st January, 1895}
\begin{letter}{
    George Bernard Shaw,\\
    Shaw's Corner,\\
    Bibbs Hall Lane,\\
    Ayot St. Lawrence, Hertfordshire\\}

\opening{Dear Shaw,}

You suck!

\closing{Sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A comparable solution can be obtained with `eso-pic` by changing, in the OP's original MWE, the `-1cm` to `-0.5cm`, inside the `\put`, as in

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=false,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
% Add code to annotate file with file name and hash of last hg cset to change the file.                                                          
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  % change reference point to page upper left                                                                                                    
  \AtPageUpperLeft{
    \put(\oddsidemargin+1in+0.5\textwidth,-0.5cm){%                                                                                                
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\textbf{shaw.tex} 09da3da30168bc8301b68b894b0414cd87ba0a16 2014-08-30 18:13 +0530 } }
  }
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{H. G. Wells}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Spade House\\ 5281 Radnor Cliff Crescent (West Side)\\ Sandgate, Kent}

\def\today{1st January, 1895}
\begin{letter}{
    George Bernard Shaw,\\
    Shaw's Corner,\\
    Bibbs Hall Lane,\\
    Ayot St. Lawrence, Hertfordshire\\}

\opening{Dear Shaw,}

You suck!

\closing{Sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the reply. Is there any way to do this using eso-pic? Also, can you explain why eso-pic is not working? Finally, could you explain briefly how your method works? This would be helpful in case I need to adjust it in future.

Comment: @FaheemMitha  When outputting with `everypage` routines, the "current" position is `\hoffset+\PageLeftMargin` from the left side of the paper, and `\voffset+\PageTopMargin` from the top of the paper.  Thus, to position absolutely on the page, I subtract these dimensions from the x and y positions (taking me to the upper left paper corner), respectively, and then add in the user specified offset distances.  The `\smash` is so that it does not affect subsequent page text.  The y-position is handled with a `\raisebox` and x-position with a `\hspace*`.  I don't know `eso-pic` to help there.

Comment: @FaheemMitha See updated answer for `eso-pic` answer.